# Problems with nested loops…

Tags: python

I’m going to explain to you in details of what I want to achieve.
I have 2 programs about dictionaries.
The code for program 1 is here:

```
import re
words = {'i':'jeg','am':'er','happy':'glad'}

text = "I am happy.".split()
translation = []

for word in text:
    word_mod = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', word.lower())
    punctuation = word[-1] if word[-1].lower() != word_mod[-1] else ''
    if word_mod in words:
        translation.append(words[word_mod] + punctuation)
    else:
        translation.append(word)
translation = ' '.join(translation).split('. ')
print('. '.join(s.capitalize() for s in translation))
```

This program has following advantages:

- You can write more than one sentence
- You get the first letter capitalized after “.”
- The program “append” the untranslated word to the output (“translation = []”)

Here is the code for program 2:

```
words = {('i',): 'jeg', ('read',): 'leste', ('the', 'book'): 'boka'}
max_group = len(max(words))

text = "I read the book".lower().split()
translation = []

position = 0
while text:
    for m in range(max_group - 1, -1, -1):
        word_mod = tuple(text[:position + m])
        if word_mod in words:
            translation.append(words[word_mod])
            text = text[position + m:]
    position += 1

translation = ' '.join(translation).split('. ')
print('. '.join(s.capitalize() for s in translation))
```

With this code you can translate idiomatic expressions or
“the book” to “boka”.
Here is how the program proceeds the codes.
This is the output:

```
1  
('i',)  
['jeg']  
['read', 'the', 'book']  
0  
()  
1  
('read', 'the')  
0  
('read',)  
['jeg', 'leste']  
['the', 'book']  
1  
('the', 'book')  
['jeg', 'leste', 'boka']  
[]  
0  
()  
Jeg leste boka
```

What I want is to implement some of the codes from program 1 into program 2.
I have tried many times with no success…
Here is my dream…:
If I change the text to the following…:

```
text = "I read the book. I read the book! I read the book? I read the book.".lower().split()
```

I want the output to be:

```
Jeg leste boka. Jeg leste boka! Jeg leste boka? Jeg leste boka.
```

So please, tweak your brain and help me with a solution…
I appreciate any reply very much!
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My solution flow would be something like this:

```
dict = ...
max_group = len(max(dict))
input = ...
textWPunc = input.lower().split()
textOnly = [re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', x) for x in input.lower().split()]
translation = []

while textOnly:
    for m in [max_group..0]:
        if textOnly[:m] in words:
            check for punctuation here using textWPunc[:m]
            if punctuation present in textOnly[:m]:
                Append translated words + punctuation
            else:
                Append only translated words
            textOnly = textOnly[m:]
            textWPunc = textWPunc[m:]

join translation to finish
```

The key part being you keep two parallel lines of text, one that you check for words to translate and the other you check for punctuation if your translation search comes up with a hit. To check for punctuation, I fed the word group that I was examining into re() like so: `re.sub('[a-z0-9]', '', wordGroup)` which will strip out all characters but no punctuation.

Last thing was that your indexing looks kind of weird to me with that **position** variable. Since you're truncating the source string as you go, I'm not sure that's really necessary. Just check the leftmost x words as you go instead of using that position variable.